# Why does drupal set a menu link which redirects to a node as the active trail rather than the node's menu link?

Tags: navigation, routes

I know the question might be hard to understand, so here's the problem:

I have this menu:

- a

  - b
  - c
- d

  - e
  - f (which has the url "/lorem/ipsum")

So, when I click on f the active trail is **d > f**, just as supposed to be.

The problem is, inside submenu a shall be another menu link which has the same link as f, i.e. "/lorem/ipsum". So I added a menu link and the menu looks like this:

- a

  - b
  - c
  - g (which links to "/lorem/ipsum")
- d

  - e
  - f (which has the url "/lorem/ipsum")

So now, when I click on the menu link **g** the site "/lorem/ipsum" opens, but now the active trail is **a > g** and not **d > f**. I just want g to be a redirect to that node/url. How to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't quite understand what exactly do you mean.

Comment: it would be better if you send the screenshot of the menu which shows the trail

Comment: see updated question

Comment: In example both g and f has same url, even if we are giving alias path menu url, it will be saved with it original url. so when menu printing it will take last url as active.

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution so far is to create a new node and add a global redirect from that node/nid plus url alias to "lorem/ipsum". This is really awkward...